# Not able to get the flat ui tags to work

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the tags control of flat ui in my asp.net mvc website but they aren't rendering at all.

[image]

```
> TypeError: $(...).tagsInput is not a function     
> 
> $(".tagsinput").tagsInput();
```

I have included all the jquery and css files as given below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {


                $(".tagsinput").tagsInput();


            });
        </script>
```

Check on Fire bug all the javascript libraries:

```
 <head>

<script src="/Content/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" style="">
<script src="/Content/js/jquery.tagsinput.js">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/%7Bmain,places%7D.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/css/flat-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/css/dropzone.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/%7Bcommon,util,controls,places_impl%7D.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/9/%7Bstats%7D.js">
</head>
```

Comment: Did you add the Jquery Library?

Comment: Make sure `jquery.tagsinput.js` is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue the  `$(".tagsinput").tagsInput();` has to be outside the document.ready and not inside it.